# navbar won't display horizontally?

Tags: html, css, navbar

[my sad navbar here](https://jsfiddle.net/j4wfa2b9/1/) I can't get my navbar to display horizontally and have tried messing with float, position, and display:inline-block. It is in an ul format and has 3 buttons in the middle with dropdown menus. Please let me know if you see what I am doing wrong and thank you!

```
    /* NAVIGATION BAR */
#nav {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
    }

# nav button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(36,60,131);
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    }

li {
    float: left;
    }

/* nav bar hover */
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;c
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(36,60,131);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    }

/* changes link color on hover */
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(36,60,131);
    color: white;
    }

/* highlights active page on nav bar */
.active {
    background-color: rgb(36,60,131);
    color: white;
    }

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    }

/* dropdown menu */
.dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    color: rgb(36,60,131);
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(36,60,131);
    color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    }

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(36,60,131);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(36,60,131);
    color: white;
    }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }


and my HTML is here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/saferide.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li style="float:left"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">about us</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="history.html">safe ride history</a>
                <a href="#">meet our dispatchers</a>
                <a href="#">core staff</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">how we operate</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">rules &amp; policies</a>
                <a href="#">how to schedule a ride</a>
                <a href="#">safe ride boundaries</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">get involved</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">volunteer or intern</a>
                <a href="#">resources</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/2uj2u5g5/

You forgot to add a `;` to one of the `width:100%` and therefore the CSS was not working correctly. You also did `li.dropdown` while your dropdown classes are not within the `li`, so that didn't work either. I would highly suggest that you add more structure to your navigation panel and keep the HTML standards in mind. Please follow some well known articles like this one: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp.

Good luck.